# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String , dynamic>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to build a reddit clone app

and the error is when clicking on edit community in mod tools[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l0uOL.png)

i was building the edit community screen it was fine until i added`return ref.read(getCommunityByNameProvider(widget.name)).when( data: (community) => Scaffold(`

the provider

```
final getCommunityByNameProvider = StreamProvider.family((ref, String name) {
  return ref
      .watch(communityControllerProvider.notifier)
      .getCommunityByName(name);
});
```

```
  Stream<Community> getCommunityByName(String name) {
    return _communities.doc(name).snapshots().map(
        (event) => Community.fromMap(event.data() as Map<String, dynamic>));
  }
```

the respiratory

```
Stream<Community> getCommunityByName(String name) {
    return _communityRepository.getCommunityByName(name);
  }
```

data model

```
        
          class Community {
  final String name;
  final String id;
  final String banner;
  final String avatar;
  final List<String> members;
  final List<String> mods
```

i use a similar method in the communities screen and it doesnt have any issues

I'm new to flutter , I have no idea what to provide , so if u need any more information please ask , I apologise for the inconvenience

Comment: Please ensure that your data is not empty(null), especially when using the Watch Map<String, dynamic> feature.

Comment: It is coming empty , when I open the problematic screen , but the it is not returning empty for another screen which uses the same provider

Comment: Please make sure that your provider setup for 'getCommunityByNameProvider' is verified and that the 'widget.name' field is not left empty.

Comment: How to do that ? Newbie here 

Answer (score 0):

As per the error
it is saying that you are trying to typecast `Null` as `Map<String, dynamic>`

check if `event.data()` is returning null in the below line

```
event.data() as Map<String, dynamic>
```

Comment: Yes it is returning null to the problematic page

Answer (score 0):

It means `event.data()` is `null`.

You have several solutions

### 1. Fix your firebase data

You have to find out in Firebase why `event.data()` is `null` (maybe the document doesn't exist?). Once done, there shouldn't be any issue anymore

### 2. Support `null`

Instead of casting directly to `Map<String, dynamic>`, make sure it is not `null`:

```dart
Stream<Community?> getCommunityByName(String name) {
  return _communities.doc(name).snapshots().map(
    (event) {
      if (event.data() == null) return `null`;
      return Community.fromMap(event.data() as Map<String, dynamic>));
  }
}
```

### 3. Filter out the `null`s

```dart
Stream<Community> getCommunityByName(String name) {
  return _communities.doc(name).snapshots().where((even) => even.data() != null).map(
    (event) => Community.fromMap(event.data() as Map<String, dynamic>),
  );
}
```

Comment: Event .data is not null as the same provider is used in another page to get the community name , and tbh I have no idea what where to paste your step 3 , sorry 